# \usepackage{inconsolata} changes \ttfamily to serif/non-monospace font

Tags: fonts, luatex, miktex, inconsolata

I am trying to compile a simple latex document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\begin{document}
  \normalfont\ttfamily
  Some text
\end{document}
```

But my output looks like this:

[image: "Some text" written with the default normal font]

Rather than the expected:

[image: "Some text" written the way I'd expect]

Removing the `\usepackage{inconsolata}` gives me the default \ttfamily font but I'd like to be able to use inconsolas.

I am using the MiKTeX distribution on Windows and while compiling, using Lualatex, I get the following output:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.06.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.6530 64-bit)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./testing_tt.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
(using cache: C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.493 seconds
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/report.cls"
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"(load luc: C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.lu
c))) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/inconsolata/inconsolata.sty"
`inconsolata-zi4' v1.112, 2017/01/04 Text macros for Inconsolata (msharpe)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex")))))
(./testing_tt.aux) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty")

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/zi4/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 4.

[1{C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(./testing_tt.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

)
 355 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 45 glue_spec, 3 attribute_lis
t, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:15,3:2,4:1,5:21,6:1,7:22,8:1,9:6
<c:/program files/miktex 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on testing_tt.pdf (1 page, 3672 bytes).
Transcript written on testing_tt.log.
```

I realise that I get a warning about a font not being available (presumably inconsolata), what I don't understand is why.

the miktex-makepk.log shows:

```
2018-01-03 01:29:03,274+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose ot1-zi4r-0 600 600 magstep(0.0)
2018-01-03 01:29:03,276+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font ot1-zi4r-0 at 600 DPI...
2018-01-03 01:29:03,286+0100 INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
2018-01-03 01:29:03,293+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2018-01-03 01:29:03,296+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-makemf.exe --verbose ot1-zi4r-0
2018-01-03 01:29:03,600+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...
2018-01-03 01:29:03,604+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ttf2pk.exe -q -t ot1-zi4r-0
2018-01-03 01:29:03,899+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font ot1-zi4r-0 could not be created.
```

I have:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled the inconsolata package through the MiKTeX packet manager (as admin)
- Made sure the the inconsolata style files are present (from what I understand this message `'inconsolata-zi4' v1.112, 2017/01/04 Text macros for Inconsolata (msharpe)` indicates that it is found as well)
- Verified the *.pfb font files are present in: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\type1\public\inconsolata

I am not sure where else to look, perhaps someone else knows what might be the issue?

Comment: I get the correct output with `pdflatex`, however

Comment: I get the following using pdflatex: `PK font ot1-zi4r-0 could not be created.´ I recognize zi4r to be connected to inconsolata

Comment: I am no `lualatex` user, but if I remember correctly it's not useful to load font packages that are meant for pdflatex/latex; that's why `fontspec` should be used (if I am right)

Comment: I didn't realize that the inconsolata package was meant for pdflatex/latex only. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, but I may be wrong, of course. (in this case, I will delete my comments)  The LuaLaTeX etc. font experts should answer this. In my opinion you should obtain some OpenType version of `inconsolata` font

Comment: @ChristianEriksson What's the reason for using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I’m no `lualatex` user either, but if I recollect correctly, using `lualatex` entails switching to the `TU` encoding by default; and, indeed, it seems that no `utzi4.fd` file exists (while both `ot1zi4.fd` and `t1zi4.fd` do exist).

Comment: @egreg well I believe it's because one of the style files I use uses, 
`fontspec` :) but perhaps I'll be able/allowed to either change that style file or I should be able to use fontspec to load incosolata as the`\ttfamily` font.

Comment: @ChristianEriksson: Have you checked whether your `pdftex.map` file has an entry for `ot1-zi4r-0` (it should point to `Inconsolata-zi4r.pfb`, suitably reencoded)?

Comment: Of course, in [my previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408566/usepackageinconsolata-changes-ttfamily-to-serif-non-monospace-font#comment1019503_408566) I actually meant “no `tuzi4.fd` file exists” (and not `utzi4.fd`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `fontspec`,

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Inconsolatazi4}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it require inconsolata being installed as a regular font usable by other programs or just the inconsolata package?

Comment: @thymaro With LuaLaTeX it's only necessary the OT font is installed in TeX Live or MiKTeX. Both distributions provide it. With XeLaTeX you need the OT font is visible as a system font.

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be using LuaLaTeX, you shouldn't load the `inconsolata` package directly. Instead, use the following instructions:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{inconsolata}
```

This setup loads the OpenType font file `Inconsolatazi4-Regular.otf`. And, if you use the combination of `\ttfamily` and `\bfseries`, the OpenType font file `Inconsolatazi4-Bold.otf` will be loaded as well -- automatically.